# posting to facebook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a large excel file with links and posts that I manually post to a facebook page I run

I've been learning more VBA recently and wanted to try to use it to automate things.

I've researched lots of web scraping videos etc and can't find a solution

I basically want VBA to open my page and post a line of text including a link. I've found how to click the search text box and type in but not the post box as this is not an input box when I inspect the element via chrome after typing in "test"  it shows:

test

tried using the get elements by id and the class name and changing the value but when I inspect the elements there's no "value there" so the object won't allow it

```
Sub posttofb()

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.navigate "www.facebook.com/kimberskitchenfitness"
ie.Visible = True

Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("_5rp7").Data -Text = "test!"

End Sub
```

I want it to click in the box. I'm going to create a dim string to change the "test" to whatever is on the excel cell i want to post

Comment: Hi @Matthew, you should use another programming language like javascript/node/puppeteer. Or Python + Jquery

Comment: Hi I don’t do programming really I just want to work through vba I’m a data analyst so get vba from writing and working in excel